# About the definition of fixed-point combinators

Tags: notation, lambda-calculus

I am reading this wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) to understand Fixed-point combinators:

> In computer science, a fixed-point combinator (or fixpoint
>   combinator[1]) is a higher-order function y that satisfies the
>   equation,  $y\ f = f\ (y\ f)$

- about the notation: if $y$ is a function, then do we write $y\ f$ instead of $y(f)$?
- is it implied that $y\ f$, which is a function, belongs to the domain of $f$?

(I hope I am not off-topic; my question is about the mathematical notation and definition rather than the application to computer science)

Comment: The parentheses are for grouping (assumed to be left-associative in the absence of parentheses), not function application.  $y(f)$ and $y f$ mean the same thing.  $f (y f)$ and $f y f$ do not; the latter is equivalent to $(f y) f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lambda calculus the only operation is function application. Because it is so common, it is usually denoted by juxtaposition. It is read as a left-associative operation, parentheses are used for grouping only.

In real-number algebra, we usually use juxtaposition for multiplication, and thus we have to invent a different notation for functions.

The syntax goes:
$$ T ::= \lambda V . T \mid T\; T \mid (T) \mid V $$
$$ V ::= x, y, z, \dots $$

The fixed-point combinator is necessary to implement recursion, seeing as there is no way to name a function definition in lambda calculus. Essentially it takes a function looking, for example, like this:
$$ f(me, x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2\cdot me(x_1 + 1, x_2 - 1) $$
and replaces every instance of $me$ with $Y(f)$:
$$ Y(f)(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2\cdot Y(f)(x_1 + 1, x_2 - 1) $$

Comment: Your last line is not recursion by any means. First you defined $f$ as three argument function but in last line you used different function with a same name $f$ which takes two arguments.

Comment: @Trismegistos corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Function in lambda calculus bind to the left so $a b c d$ means $((a b) c) d$ where $x y$ means calling function $x$ with parameter $y$. Therefore you first call function $a$ with parameter $b$ then you get resulting function $u = (a b)$ and you call function $u$ with parameter $c$ and you get resulting function $v = (u c) = (a b) c$. Then you call $v$ with parameter $d$ so you get $v d = ((a b) c) d$ or omitting parentheses $v d = a b c d$. You should really start reading on some basic syntax of lambda calculus if you want to read about fixed-point combinators.